# Locks at C# to use prevent multiple threads or events to use same variable value

Tags: c#, locking

I want to free my application from sql, because I do not have a large db. I want to hold my data on memory, so my application will run faster.

My question here is that I've a key pool, and a key can be used by only 4 clients, I want to lock each key when it is registered to a client so I will use:

```
lock(key)
{
  assignKeyToClient(clientId);
}
```

If I use that, will lock use the copy of the key or lock the original "key" on ram and does free it after finishing assignment?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are confused on what the [`lock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) statement means - it is only for concurrency management - it ensures that the section of code it is protecting (the "critical section") is only entered by one thread at a time.

This has nothing to do with user data, i.e. client id's or keys. To manage unique client id's you could use something like a [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx). When you do assign your keys you should use a lock only if there is more than one thread executing this section of code. If that's the case use a private readonly object variable to lock on within your class instance to make sure the same key is only assigned once:

```
private readonly object myLock = new object();
private Dictionary<int> assignedKeys = new Dictionary<int>();
...

lock(myLock)
{
  int key = PickAKeyHere();
  AssignKeyToClient(key, clientId);
  assignedKeys[key] = clientId; //keep track of which client is assigned what key 
}
```

Comment: thanks for the information you give. i've a question, my clients have already unique id's, but i want to have 4 clients at same room, but a 5th one may not join the room. I've room id's and i want to seperate clients randomly to rooms. That's why i want to assing each user on room and each room may maximum 4 clients. as i understood if i will have a function registers a client to a room, and if i will have that function as " critial code block " each request must wait for lock is opened. This is not good because what will happen if some room-find requests fall ?

Comment: If it fails and throws an exception, that thread will leave the lock (and the other threads will be able to enter)

Comment: @softwareMonster: In this case the `PickAKeyHere` method could only return a valid key if there's a spot left in the rooms, if there's no room you would have to handle that in your own code by evaluating the return code (or change the whole method altogether to return a boolean to check if there's room left), that's not what locks are for.

Comment: a question: is there any method i can understand that the lock is active ? [this is an exception ? ] thanks !

Comment: @softwaremonster you have to keep track of assigned keys yourself, the lock just guarantees that the small section of code it guards is only executed by one thread at a time, but this should only be for a few milliseconds, it's not meant to block out for a long period of time, that's where your application logic comes in - please do read up on threading and locks, it's an important concept to grasp if you want to build multithreaded applications in the future!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have a large database then all your database queries should be < 1 second. You don't have any reason to put all the data in memory. The performance difference by querying the database directly or querying it from memory is negligible.

All you're really doing is over complicating your application. Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: you're phill, but i'm coding on C# things faster, if i'm working with sql statement i've got more confused :( even because i'm working on a tcp-socket communication to work with objectst are easier, so that i want to free myself from sql